Drawing an Ellipse in a QGraphics scene from a dxf file
I am importing a dxf file to my program with dxflib which is then painted on to the scene. So far I have text, circles, lines and arcs working. I can't figure out the ellipse.
Here is the data from dxflib
/**
 * Ellipse Data.
 */
struct DXFLIB_EXPORT DL_EllipseData {
    /**
     * Constructor.
     * Parameters: see member variables.
     */
    DL_EllipseData(double cx, double cy, double cz,
                   double mx, double my, double mz,
                   double ratio,
                   double angle1, double angle2)
        : cx(cx),
          cy(cy),
          cz(cz),
          mx(mx),
          my(my),
          mz(mz),
          ratio(ratio),
          angle1(angle1),
          angle2(angle2) {
    }

    /*! X Coordinate of center point. */
    double cx;
    /*! Y Coordinate of center point. */
    double cy;
    /*! Z Coordinate of center point. */
    double cz;

    /*! X coordinate of the endpoint of the major axis. */
    double mx;
    /*! Y coordinate of the endpoint of the major axis. */
    double my;
    /*! Z coordinate of the endpoint of the major axis. */
    double mz;

    /*! Ratio of minor axis to major axis.. */
    double ratio;
    /*! Startangle of ellipse in rad. */
    double angle1;
    /*! Endangle of ellipse in rad. */
    double angle2;
};


And here is my creator function
void Creator::addEllipse(const DL_EllipseData &data)
{
    DimItem dimItem;
    dimItem.dimType = DimType::Ellipse;
    dimItem.colour = attributes.getColor();
    dimItem.lineStyle = QString::fromStdString(attributes.getLinetype());
    dimItem.cen = QPointF(data.cx, data.cy);
    dimItem.majorX = data.mx;
    dimItem.majorY = data.my;
    dimItem.ratio = data.ratio;
    dimItem.angle1 = data.angle1;
    dimItem.angle2 = data.angle2;

    double lineStartX = data.cx - data.mx;
    double lineStartY = data.cy - data.my;
    double lineEndX = data.cx + data.mx;
    double lineEndY = data.cy + data.my;

    dimItem.line = QLineF(lineStartX, lineStartY, lineEndX, lineEndY);

    if (blockItem)
        block.dimItems.append(dimItem);
    else
        dimList->append(dimItem);
}

Here is my code to import the dxf file, the *dimlist holds all the DimItems from the creator function
void DxfImport::importDxfFileToScene(QGraphicsScene *scene, QVector<Creator::DimItem> *dimList, QPointF offset)
{
    float pixelSize = 0.08;

    for (Creator::DimItem &dim : *dimList) {
        double x1 = dim.line.p1().x();
        double y1 = dim.line.p1().y();
        double x2 = dim.line.p2().x();
        double y2 = dim.line.p2().y();
        double x3 = dim.node3.x();
        double y3 = dim.node3.y();
        double cx = dim.cen.x();
        double cy = dim.cen.y();
        double rad = dim.rad;
        double majorX = dim.majorX;
        double majorY = dim.majorY;
        double ratio = dim.ratio;
        double majorAxisLength = QLineF(cx + majorX, cy + majorY, cx - majorX, cy - majorY).length();
        double minorAxisLength = majorAxisLength * ratio;

        double blockOffsetX = dim.blockOffsetX;
        double blockOffsetY = dim.blockOffsetY;
        double blockAngle = dim.blockAng;
        double blockInsPointX = blockOffsetX;
        double blockInsPointY = blockOffsetY;

        x1 -= offset.x();
        y1 -= offset.y();
        x2 -= offset.x();
        y2 -= offset.y();
        x3 -= offset.x();
        y3 -= offset.y();
        cx -= offset.x();
        cy -= offset.y();
        majorX -= offset.x();
        majorY -= offset.y();
        blockInsPointX -= offset.x();
        blockInsPointY -= offset.y();

        x1 = x1 / pixelSize;
        y1 = y1 / pixelSize;
        x2 = x2 / pixelSize;
        y2 = y2 / pixelSize;
        x3 = x3 / pixelSize;
        y3 = y3 / pixelSize;
        cx = cx / pixelSize;
        cy = cy / pixelSize;
        rad = rad / pixelSize;
        majorX = majorX / pixelSize;
        majorY = majorY / pixelSize;
        majorAxisLength = majorAxisLength / pixelSize;
        minorAxisLength = minorAxisLength / pixelSize;
        blockOffsetX = blockOffsetX / pixelSize;
        blockOffsetY = blockOffsetY / pixelSize;
        blockInsPointX = blockInsPointX / pixelSize;
        blockInsPointY = blockInsPointY / pixelSize;

        x1 += blockOffsetX;
        y1 += blockOffsetY;
        x2 += blockOffsetX;
        y2 += blockOffsetY;
        x3 += blockOffsetX;
        y3 += blockOffsetY;
        cx += blockOffsetX;
        cy += blockOffsetY;
        majorX += blockOffsetX;
        majorY += blockOffsetY;

        y1 = (MIRROR_COORDINATE - y1) + MIRROR_COORDINATE;
        y2 = (MIRROR_COORDINATE - y2) + MIRROR_COORDINATE;
        y3 = (MIRROR_COORDINATE - y3) + MIRROR_COORDINATE;
        cy = (MIRROR_COORDINATE - cy) + MIRROR_COORDINATE;
        majorY = (MIRROR_COORDINATE - majorY) + MIRROR_COORDINATE;
        blockInsPointY = (MIRROR_COORDINATE - blockInsPointY) + MIRROR_COORDINATE;

        // Pen Configuration
        QPen pen;

        // Colour
        int itemColour = dim.colour;
        if((itemColour < 0)  || (itemColour > 255) || (itemColour == 7))
            itemColour = 0;

        QColor rgbColour = rgbData[itemColour];
        pen.setColor(rgbColour);

        // Style
        QString lineStyle = dim.lineStyle.toLower();
        Qt::PenStyle penStyle;

        if ((lineStyle.contains("dash") && lineStyle.contains("dot")) || lineStyle.contains("acad_iso10")) {
            penStyle = Qt::DashDotLine;
        } else if (lineStyle.contains("dash") || lineStyle.contains("hidden") || lineStyle.contains("acad_iso02")) {
            penStyle = Qt::DashLine;
        } else if (lineStyle.contains("dot") || lineStyle.contains("acad_iso07")) {
            penStyle = Qt::DotLine;
        } else if (lineStyle.contains("divide")) {
            penStyle = Qt::DashDotLine;
        } else {
            penStyle = Qt::SolidLine;
        }

        pen.setStyle(penStyle);

        // Width
        double lineWidthInPix = dim.width;
        if(lineWidthInPix < 8)
            lineWidthInPix = 8;

        lineWidthInPix /= 50;
        lineWidthInPix = lineWidthInPix / pixelSize;

        if(lineWidthInPix > 16)
            lineWidthInPix = 16;

        pen.setWidthF(lineWidthInPix);

        // Text
        QFont textFont;
        textFont.setPointSize(dim.height / pixelSize);
        textFont.setFamily("DejaVu Sans");
        double height = dim.height / pixelSize;
        QString text = dim.text;
        float fAngle = dim.angle;
        double angle = qRadiansToDegrees(fAngle);
        angle = -angle;

        if(dim.textItem){
            QPointF vJOffset;
            int vJustification = dim.vJustification;
            if(vJustification == 0) //Base
                vJOffset = QPointF(0,0);
            else if(vJustification == 1) //Bottom
                vJOffset = QPointF(0,-(height/4));
            else if(vJustification == 2) //Middle
                vJOffset = QPointF(0,height/2);
            else if(vJustification == 3) //Top
                vJOffset = QPointF(0,height);

            QGraphicsTextItem *textItem = scene->addText(text,textFont);
            textItem->setPos(x1, y1);
            textItem->setDefaultTextColor(rgbColour);
            textItem->setRotation(angle);
        }
        else{
            if(dim.dimType == DimType::Line || dim.dimType == DimType::Dim)
                scene->addLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,pen);
            else if(dim.dimType == DimType::Circle)
                scene->addEllipse(cx-rad,cy-rad,rad*2,rad*2, pen);
            else if (dim.dimType == DimType::P3Arc)
            {
                float startAngle = dim.startAngle;
                float spanAngle = dim.spanAngle;
                if (startAngle > spanAngle)
                    spanAngle = spanAngle + (360 - startAngle);
                else
                    spanAngle = spanAngle - startAngle;

                startAngle *= 16;
                spanAngle *= 16;

                QPainterPath arcPath;
                arcPath.arcMoveTo(cx - rad, cy - rad, rad * 2, rad * 2, startAngle / 16);
                arcPath.arcTo(cx - rad, cy - rad, rad * 2, rad * 2, startAngle / 16, spanAngle / 16);

                QGraphicsPathItem* arcItem = new QGraphicsPathItem(arcPath);
                arcItem->setPen(pen);

                scene->addItem(arcItem);
            }
            else if (dim.dimType == DimType::Ellipse)
            {
                double angle = atan2(majorY, majorX) * (180/M_PI);
                angle = qRadiansToDegrees(angle);
                angle = -angle;

                QRectF boundingRect(
                    cx - majorAxisLength / 2.0,
                    cy - minorAxisLength / 2.0,
                    majorAxisLength,
                    minorAxisLength
                    );

                QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipseItem = scene->addEllipse(boundingRect.normalized(), pen);
                ellipseItem->setTransformOriginPoint(cx, cy);
                ellipseItem->setRotation(angle);
            }
        }
    }
}

I have tried using both QPainterPath and QGraphicsPathItem, and QGraphicsEllipseItem with this calculation but neither seem to work correctly.
The shape and size of the ellipse seems to be correct but the angle at which it's rotated is wrong.
I have tried using atan2 to calculate the correct angle but it doesnt seem to work. I'm at a loss at this point.

You're multiplying by (180/M_PI) which already gives you degrees, so you should not call again qRadiansToDegrees(angle);.

Note that vector oriented Qt objects have functions that can be used as "helpers" in place of pure math functions: they may be a bit more costly, but are often easier to use (and also preferable for readability purposes). For instance, you can get the angle with this: QLineF(cx, cy, mx, my).angle().

double rotationAngle = QLineF(cx, cy, cx + majorX, cy + majorY).angle();
rotationAngle = fmod(rotationAngle, 360.0);
if (rotationAngle < 0)
rotationAngle += 360.0;
QRectF boundingRect(
cx - majorAxisLength / 2.0,
cy - minorAxisLength / 2.0,
majorAxisLength,
minorAxisLength
);
QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipseItem = scene>addEllipse(boundingRect.normalized(), pen);
ellipseItem->setTransformOriginPoint(cx, cy);
ellipseItem->setRotation(rotationAngle);
The dimensions of the ellipse are correct but the rotation is still wrong
@musicamante

Doing fmod() and +=360 is useless as QLine angle() is already normalized (>= 0 and <360). Also, the docs are clear: angle() uses standard Cartesian convention (counter clockwise), while setRotation() is clockwise, so you need to use the negative of that. If you still don't get the correct result, please [edit] your post and provide a [mre] (only what's related to the ellipse) of your current code, the data of a test ellipse, and images of what you get from it and the expected result.
